# Google App Engine deployment issue- main app not found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, app.yaml

I am trying to deploy my app using Google App Engine. I have edited app.yaml to reflect the flexible environment and also gave all the app information. Below is the app.yaml file.

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Once the deployment is in progress, I am getting the following error

```
[2018-08-24 06:57:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-08-24 06:57:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
[2018-08-24 06:57:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-08-24 06:57:14 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
App Deployed
Failed to find application: 'main'
[2018-08-24 06:57:14 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
[2018-08-24 06:57:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-08-24 06:57:14 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

Please note that App Deployed is the line in my print statement. It is getting executed. But the deployment is getting failed

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where is your main.py file located? It should be inside the folder where you are running `gcloud app deploy command`.

Comment: Yes @Yurci .. It is inside the folder where I have app.yaml, requirements.txt and the python code as well (main.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.yaml`, you're starting gunicorn with `gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app`. This tells it to look for the object `app` in the file `main.py`

[The error you're getting comes from gunicorn](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/328e509260ae70de6c04c5ba885ee17960b3ced5/gunicorn/util.py#L368)) and occurs when you have a `main.py` file, but it does not have an `app` object in it.

You probably want to set up a Flask app as follows:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

See a full example app here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#hello_world_code_review

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue.

```
Failed to find application: 'main'
```

The reason in my case was that I had a directory called also `main` in the root project directory.

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 user  staff    64 Nov 30 10:12 main
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff  1178 Nov 29 20:58 main.py
```

I guess gunicorn got confused.
The solution (worked for me): to rename `main` directory.

P.S. Just don't rename it to `code` directory. It will cause another issue with debugging in PyCharm. :)

Answer (score 1):

My folder structure is looks llike this the `main.py` is not in the `root` directory how I can specify this in `app.yaml` file.

```
/app
 |__main.py
app.yaml
```